# Test Assertion REST API best practices

Tags: rest, automated-tests, asp.net-web-api2

we are doing API test automation and would like to  have suggestions on the best practices regarding the assertion of the response

Problem Statement

we have an API /Orders/{ID}  which basically give details for a given order ,now the status code will always be 200 for successful but response might have extra values for different type of order and for other it will be null , for ex : Discount attribute can be null and it can be decimal value depending upon the input payload we have sent .

Currently, we have added CSV file with different input and using the TT file to generate the test method with different input and there is no issue with that and  have different assert statement for each type , so we have created different AssertValidator class and base class  which will have common properties  check and each specif will check for the extra properties and create a factory class which will have instance of the all the validator class and will pick the right one depending upon input

I would like to know whether this scalable approach or have an extra column where  i can set the expected properties for each entries in form of JSON and generate the assert statement accordingly.

which is more scalable and maintable why ?

Also please suggest if there are better approaches

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for also passing in the expected result if that's doable in your case as I think it's faster to scale. Having a factory for the AssertValidator and all that is fine for production code, but given these are tests it's easier to just add a new line in the test case with some input and expected value, rather than adding a new AssertValidator.